# Permissions Error when running an exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions

I have seen a lot of issues regarding this. For some reason, mine is different. When i I look in the Security properties, and i have full permission. However, when i click the exe, i get this error:

[image]

After that, the `exe` just deletes itself out of the folder, and i have to re-download it.?
I have tried rebooting, disabling my antivirus. And nothing seems to help. I have no idea why? I am Administrator on my computer too.

Here is what i have done:

- Uninstalled Norton Antivirus
- Rebooted Computer
- Removed all Anti Virus Software
- I had all permissions for the file

Comment: Have you tried using a vile such as [unlocker](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/unlocker.html) to see if any process is using it?

Comment: No, but let me try

Comment: @chipperyman573 no luck :/

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* you've entirely disabled your antivirus? I had the same problem with a particular file, where the AV was wiping it out as soon as I clicked on it. Make sure you don't have multiple AVs running too - for example, Avast and MS Security Essentials. You might be disabling one but forgetting the other. :)

That said, in your antivirus software (whatever it is,) add an exception for the filename or directory *before* you even navigate to the file. That should keep it from getting blown away from the on-access scan.

Needless to say, be careful when whitelisting a file from your AV - it's usually removing access for a reason. Make sure you're 100% sure the file is legit... or willing to fix your computer afterwards.

Comment: Let me check...i even uninstalled Norton Antivirus, which worked for about 10 mins, then i got the error again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got nothing on this if it isn't something AV-like that's killing the file. Even on server OSes with untrusted files (when I pull CPU-Z over the network to check system specs, for example,) Windows just blocks the file by default - not deletes it.